# MVC Iterating through the model gives complilation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to iterate through model using simple for loop . but it gives me compilation error. can anyone tell what is incorrect here?

```
List<EmpModel> models = new List<EmpModel>();
....
....
for loop (....)
{
emp.name = "somename";
emp.agg = 20;
emp.add  ="some add";

models.Add(emp);
}

for (int i = 1; i < models.Count(); i++)
        {
            EmpModel m1, m2;

            m1 = models.IndexOf(i - 1);
            m2 = models.IndexOf(i);

            CompareModels(m1, m2);
        }
```

Comment: it would be really nice if you could post the actual code AND the error message you get and when your exception is raised.

Comment: where is `emp` declared?

Comment: @markpsmith sowhere in "...." I guess :)

Comment: While we are at it: Please add the code for your `CompareModels(EmpModel m1, EmpModel m2)` method.

Comment: The error is in line m1 = models.IndexOf(i - 1); and m2 = models.Indexof(i). Error is "The best overloaded method match for system.collections.generic.List<EmpModel>.indexOf<EmpModel> has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `EmpModel` parameter for IndexOf, because your List uses `EmpModel` as the type. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to do this in your for loop, you can use an iterator and use the overloaded `Select()` method:

```
List<EmpModel> models = new List<EmpModel>();
...
var tempList = models.Select((v,i) => new {val = v, idx = i});

for(int i = 1; i < tempList.Count(); i++)
{
   EmpModel m1, m2;
   m1 = models.FirstOrDefault(x => x.index = i-1);
   m2 = models.FirstOrDefault(x => x.index = i);
   CompareModels(m1, m2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, using m1 = models[i-1] and m2 = models[i] solves the compilation problem.